# Accessing .NET assemblies via COM in PHP

Tags: c#, php, .net

I have a .net Web service Method `CheckCustomerLicense`, and this method returns a C sharp serialized object, I am calling this method via Soap from PHP.

I am getting the serialized object which is binary formatted and not in XML.

Exactly this is what I am facing:
I want to access that data as object in PHP, but to do this I must desirealize it, and since its a .NET object I want to use .NET built in class `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary` via COM.

But its not working.

When I use class `System.Collections.Stack` it is working ie .net is getting accessed.
But why it doesn't for class `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary`?

The Code Is Shown Below:

Working...

```
<?php
 $stack = new COM("System.Collections.Stack");
 $stack->Push(".Net");
  $stack->Push("Hello ");
  echo $stack->Pop() . $stack->Pop();
 ?>
```

Not Working

```
 <?php
  $obj = new COM("System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary");
 ?>
```

Please Help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only put the namespace, you need the full class name. The class is called `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Sidenote: who decided a webservice serializing via SOAP should send something that is binary serialized? That seems... well... "strange" to put it mildly.

Comment: Thanks.. Its Accessible now, Can you tell me that how exactly to access data as an Object in php now.

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with PHP. As a C# programmer, I can tell you I would never send something binary serialized. I'm not even sure it will work, you will need to know the .NET type of the object you got. Binary serialization is one big bad mess if you aren't using C#, too. Can you ask the programmer of your webservice to provide a sane interface instead?

Comment: No I cant ask like that Because the Same Object has been already accessed in multiple C# application(Done By Other C# Programmers),
So the same object I have to access for Licensing...

Comment: If Suppose The Returning Data is In XML format, Then is that Possible Access Via PHP?

Comment: SOAP already *is* Xml serialization, so I have a hard time finding a reason why one would serialize data inside this serialization *again*. Maybe you can talk with the webservice guys, you may have misunderstood something. I cannot believe they did extra work just to make it harder for you.

Comment: Will I send The screen Shot of My soap Result to U? So that U will come to know exactly how they are serialized it as you are expirienced with C#...
give me ur mail ID, I will forward you the Screen shot.

Comment: Sorry, I don't do email help. Why don't you add it to your question here or post a new one.

Comment: Its Asking For atleast 10 reputation Source.

Comment: Maybe you have a wsdl to post?

Comment: http://mail.ucm.com.au/eToolsLicenseWebService/eToolsLicenseWebUpdateService.asmx?WSDL

Also have a look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554573/deserializing-net-object-from-php-using-com