# Deserializing .Net Object From PHP Using COM

Tags: c#, php

I have a .net Web service Method 'CheckCustomerLicense', and this method returns a C sharp serialized object, I am calling this method via Soap from PHP.

I am getting the serialized object which is binary formatted and not in XML.

I want to access that data as object in PHP, but to do this I must desirealize it, and since its a .NET object I want to use .NET built in class 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter' via COM.

The Code I am Using For This Is Shown Below:

```
<?php
class eToolsLicenseNew
{
} 

$url='http://mail.ucm.com.au/eToolsLicenseWebService/eToolsLicenseWebUpdateService.asmx?WSDL';
$soap = new SoapClient($url, array(
"trace" => 1,           // enable trace to view what is happening 
"exceptions" => 1,      // disable exceptions "cache_wsdl" => 1)
 );

 try {
 $customer=array('customerId'=>'12345');
$result=$soap->CheckCustomerLicense($customer);
//print_r($result);

$obj = new COM("System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter");
$object=new eToolsLicenseNew();
 $object=$obj->Deserialize($result); // call to deserilize method
}
catch (SoapFault $e)
 { 
echo "Error: {$e->faultstring}";
 }
 ?>
```

But When I call 'Deserializing Method' Giving Internal Server Error....
Other than that every thing is fine, Can Any one is there to help me... Please...

Comment: Are you sure this byte array you get is an .NET object? It simply does not make sense for the service to do this. You would need a .NET dll containing this type to deserialize it. What would be the methods of that type and what would you want to do with it?

Comment: Ya.. 100% sure. From that array I want to access the variables in that for perticuler checks of licensing.

Comment: If You have Any wsdl that returns pure xml, please share it with me..
I just want to test that if I get the return data in xml then is that possible to access it via PHP as an object or Not.. So that I can Inform my web service provider to return data in xml format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data your receive is a byte array. If it contains a .NET binary formatted object, you will need to have a BinaryFormatter to deserialize it. A binary formatters [Deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.deserialize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method however, does not take a byte array. It takes a stream of any kind. The simplest conversion method from byte array to a stream is using a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx). This takes a byte array as constructor parameter.

```
var bytes = new byte[50]; // example byte array

using(var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    var obj = (YourExpectedType)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

This is what the C# code would look like, you will need to adapt it to the COM/PHP variant.

Again, if this is really the case, someone is sending a binary serialized object via XML serialized SOAP to someone, then the first someone needs to learn how to code webservices. Because this is not an interoperable webservice, this is C#-to-C# communication wasting time using SOAP.